# align columns headers with cells values in a text file that exported from a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, windows

I export my data from a DGV and align them with a space delimiter and it is working good for me. i also export the headers before the cells values. the thing that i want to do but i can not is aligning and adjusting the cells with headers to see them as a table that its members are separated by a delimiter (here space). my means is i want to see cells values right below the headers (if they have smaller or equal lengths) and headers text right on the top of the cells values if header length is less than cells values lengths), in the other word, Keeping cells values and their related headers together.
thanks in advance.

What i have been tried:

```
int RowsCount = DataTable.Rows.Count;
int ColumnsCount = DataTable.Columns.Count;
var newline = System.Environment.NewLine;
var delimiter = " ";
var copied= new StringBuilder();
List<int> clmnLocation = new List<int>() {};



string header = "";
      for (int c = 0; c < DataTable.Columns.Count; c++)
      {
header = header + Convert.ToString(DataTable.Columns[c].ColumnName).Replace(" ", "") + delimiter;

//Count header length to get the padright() value and put in a list<int>
         clmnLocation.Add(header.Length);
      }

// Export titles: 
      for (int c = 0; c < DataTable.Columns.Count; c++)          copied.Append(Convert.ToString(DataTable.Columns[c].ColumnName).Replace(" ","") + delimiter);

//Append A Line After Header.
       clipboard_string.Append(newline);

                    //Cells
                    for (int i = 0; i <RowsCount; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <ColumnsCount; j++)
                        {
                            if (j > 0)
    copied.Append(DataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString().PadRight(clmnLocation[j]) + delimiter);
                            else
               copied.Append(DataTable.Rows[i][j].ToString() + delimiter);
                        }
                        copied.Append(newline);
                    }

                    WordDoc.Content.Text = copied.ToString();
```

Comment: i ma using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

Comment: You need to decide how the alignment shall be done: Either by inserting the right number of spaces to the right or left of each data chunk or be creating  tabs in the receiving document and inserting tab characters between fields. For the former you can use the string.padLeft/Right functions.

Comment: i have counted headers text length from left to right and .PadRight(before header length), but everything will get mix up. thanks for your answer TaW.